# Angular what I need to use? map? pipe? tap?

Tags: json, angular, typescript

On my component init I'm getting data from the server

```
 import {Rules} from "../../interfaces/interfaces";
 rules: Rules
 ngOnInit() {
  this.tt = this.rulesService.getUserClientRules().subscribe(
   t => {
     console.log(t)
     console.log(t.clientRules.canAll)
     this.rules = t.clientRules
   },
   error => {
    console.log(error.error.message)
   }
  )
 }
```

My service code is

```
getUserClientRules(): Observable<Rules> {
return this.http.get<Rules>('/api/rules/getClientUserRules/')}
```

and I have interface like:

```
export interface Rules {
 clientRules: any
}
```

I'm getting response like this:

**{clientRules: {canAll: true, canSee: false}}**

How I can push this object into my rules object? I want to use it like **rules.canAll** or **rules.canSeeAll**...

I need this strucrure rules { canAll: true, canSee: true } I need to use it for the checks like *ngIf="rules.canSee"

**Thank you** for your responses!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can define props into Rules interface like this.

```
export interface Rules { 
    clientRules: { canAll: boolean, canSee: boolean, canSeeAll: boolean}
}
```

But if your response may have many variations I suggest you to use `any` type

Comment: thanks you for responce. but I need this strucrure rules { canAll: true, canSee: true }
I need to use it for the checks like *ngIf="rules.canSee"

Answer (score 0):

Remove this.tt you dont need any. Simple do in subscription method. You dooing good.